# SIS Graphics Driver absent (reported as Gallium), making the computer too slow

Tags: drivers, graphics

My desktop is having the following problem. I installed UBUNTU 16.04 LTS i386 Desktop and the computer is being too slow, reaching 100% processor only by pointing the mouse in any icon and making its legend appears. In the System Monitor, the compiz uses a lot of processing. The CPU might be doing the graphics work instead of the GPU. The computer is almost unusable in any task because of this.

The command

```
lspci | grep -i vga
```

returns

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 65x/M650/740 PCI/AGP VGA Display Adapter
```

while the command

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-sis
```

returns nothing.

When I execute in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-sis
```

the package can't be found.

I tried several things from the internet, none solved. I selected to use third-party softwares during the installation and in Additional Drivers.

I have already tried in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Yet the problem continues.

I have Deepin-15.3-i386 installed as a multi-boot and it also has the same problem. On the other hand, Windows XP works great.

Can someone help me?

**Specifications:**

The computer is a View Tech desktop

Processor Intel® Celeron(R) CPU 1.80GHz

Graphics Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)

Kernel 4.8.0-36-generic

Thanks

Comment: The driver in question was *removed* from Ubuntu - see [Bug Report #1368330](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-sis/+bug/1368330).  It was removed in Debian, and that was followed in Ubuntu.  This looks like it's partly related to the newer Xorg version that started shipping with Utopic (14.10).

Comment: With the specs you state, I think you should be using Lubuntu instead of Ubuntu.  With the age of the system and the speed of the processor there, using standard Ubuntu will result in a massive strain on the system; you may be better with Lubuntu which doesn't need as much of a graphics slowdown.

Comment: EDIT: After updates, the Kernel is now 4.10.0-38-generic. I would like to use Ubuntu instead of Lubuntu if this is possible on my system.

Comment: 16.04 is a bit of a beast, for the specs you've indicated I would *not* recommend using standard Ubuntu 16.04 on that system, especially since it's a 32-bit system and therefore has its own evil headaches to work through.  Your Celeron processor, coupled with the graphics driver not being available, coupled with the 3GB cap on RAM on your machine (I'm guessing you have 1 or 2GB in there), Ubuntu is not going to run smoothly on your system (though Lubuntu might)

Comment: Once the driver was removed from Ubuntu, if I install Lubuntu will it come with the SIS driver?

Comment: No the issue is that the driver was removed from Ubuntu and all official variants starting with 14.10.  If you really need the driver then you are stuck on 14.04, and then after 14.04 end of life’s you will have to work without drivers.